# some unicode arrow look strange in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with C#

[image: Buttons]

```
    btnAddAll.Text = "\u21C9";
    btnRemoveAll.Text = "\u21C7";
```

Font is default: Microsoft Sans Serif

My question is about the look of the first and last button and how to fix this.

Comment: What Font are you using?

Comment: `\u21C7` and `\u21C9` result in those arrows, get the unicode values for the correct arrows, [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/) is a list

Comment: [Seems to right](http://unicode-table.com/de/search/?q=21C9) - For other arrows [see here](http://unicode-table.com/de/blocks/arrows/)

Comment: Gunter, he is using the correct ones. But they do not display correctly on the form.

Comment: Try another font to see if the look is resolved.

Comment: The font is the same on all 4 arrows and only 2 are corrupt. I have also tried to resize the buttons, but also without success.

Comment: @eddywhite I understand it is the same, but just try a different one and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Probably not - I'll remove the comment if I can.

Comment: What font size do you use? - Here the arrows all come out fine with ms sans serif. __Other_:  fonts show some differences between the upper an lower arrow..

Comment: changing the font does not change anything. But the size is the thing! thx TaW. It looks like all sizes below 18pt are corrupt. But only for doubleArrows

Comment: Works for me when I use a button with font set to `Microsoft Sans Serif, 20.25pt`. It also works fine a 12pt, but the arrows are rather small (but they look right when I paste a screen dump into Paint.Net and zoom it in).

Comment: I don't see any problems even with smaller fonts. Did you make any changes to the display sizes, maybe enlarged them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code I just wrote and it works perfectly, try it;

```
button1.Text = "\u21C7";
button1.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", button1.Height / 2);
button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
button2.Text = "\u2192";
button2.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", button1.Height / 2);
button2.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
button3.Text = "\u2190";
button3.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", button1.Height / 2);
button3.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
button4.Text = "\u21C9";
button4.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", button1.Height / 2);
button4.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]